# Making an enemy AI that follows a set path

Tags: python-3.x, artificial-intelligence

So I'm making a game for a CS project at school that is based on the game alien isolation (but top down 2D) and I am not sure where to start with the alien's methods of hunting the player. I would quite like to make a neural network however I'm not sure how to make one specific to my problem (e.g. the data given to the network, etc).
I would like the alien to follow a set path that is drawn on the map and essentially be able to intelligently follow/hunt the player without getting stuck at a dead end on the path for example.

I've already tried messing around with a simple algorithm which based the desired direction on x and y positions of the last known position of the player. But this lead to the alien getting stuck and being generally unintelligent. There's not any code to look at really because I need to completely rethink this, but it might be useful seeing t=how the alien checks whats paths are available, just for context.

```
def navigate(self, player, window):
    available = []

    nodes = [node_pos1, node_pos2, node_pos3, node_pos4]

    //nodes are the points just around the center of the alien which.. 
    //..detect the colour to check for available paths

    for node_no in range(len(nodes)):
        // checks the colour at each node
        if Graphics.get_at(background, nodes[node_no]) == (0, 255, 0, 255):
            available.append(self.direction_index[node_no])

    if not available:    // if no paths, it will find the nearest path
        self.find_path()

    self.sight(player, window)    // looks for player
    speed = self.speeds[self.status]    // sets the speed
    self.status(available, speed)    // runs the move type
```

I understand this is quite a big ask but I'm looking for some pointers of how to start a neural network for this problem at the very least.

Comment: I don't think neural networks are necessary here, just a BFS or giving your aliens some random movement once in a while to "unstuck" them. If you do want to go down the rabbit hole of neural networks here's part 0 of a 10 part series on reinforcement learning in tensorflow - https://medium.com/emergent-future/simple-reinforcement-learning-with-tensorflow-part-0-q-learning-with-tables-and-neural-networks-d195264329d0

Comment: I agree with @Primusa . But if you still want to use machine learning you might want to consider reading up on NEAT http://nn.cs.utexas.edu/downloads/papers/stanley.ec02.pdf (Its a different technique to train a network (better 'to create a network that can solve your task') based on evolution, which should suit the problem quite nicely)

Comment: Okay thank you I'll look into both. It is important that the alien is intelligent as it is the only enemy in the game and it needs to be feared which is why I'm still not sure because making a complex algorithm that seems intelligent enough might be more time consuming in the long run.

Comment: You don't really need "artificial intelligence" here, it just needs to look like it. Videogames where the bad guy hunted the good guy have existed long time before neural network could possibly be applied in a reasonable time. You could probably search for the Pacman "scent" antiobject pattern and see if that works in your case.

Comment: That does sound promising actually thanks. If the alien sees the player it will store the players coordinate at that point to a variable called 'last_detect' so that it knows the position where the player was last seen. My issue is creating something that knows how to use the paths I've marked out and then using that information.